# При перетаскивании карты менять url

Tags: yandex-maps-api

В прошлой версии 1.1 был хороший пример, если перетаскиваешь карту, то меняются параметры в url адресной строки, т.е. можно ссылку на карту кинуть кому-то.

Отрывок:

```js
 // Получаем параметры из URLа
            var params = {
                ll : getParam("ll"),    // Центр карты
                spn : getParam("spn"),  // Линейный размер области
                t : getParam("t")       // Тип карты
            };

            map.addControl(new YMaps.TypeControl([YMaps.MapType.PMAP, YMaps.MapType.SATELLITE, YMaps.MapType.PHYBRID]));
            // Если в урле заданы необходимые параметры
            if (params.ll && params.spn ) {
               // Центрируем карту в нужном месте
               map.setType(YMaps.MapType.PMAP);
               var bounds = YMaps.GeoBounds.fromCenterAndSpan(YMaps.GeoPoint.fromString(params.ll), YMaps.Size.fromString(params.spn));
               map.setBounds(bounds);
            } else {
            // По умолчанию карта центрируется как надо
            map.setCenter(new YMaps.GeoPoint(32.902004, 67.932039), 13, YMaps.MapType.PMAP);
            }
            // Динамически формируем URL
            YMaps.Events.observe(map, [map.Events.BoundsChange, map.Events.TypeChange],  function () {
                document.location.hash = "&ll=" + map.getCenter().toString() +
                                         "&spn=" + map.getBounds().getSpan().toString(6)
            });
            
            // Получение параметра из URLа
            function getParam (name, location) {
                location = location || window.location.hash;
                var res = location.match(new RegExp('[#&]' + name + '=([^&]*)', 'i'));
                return (res && res[1] ? res[1] : '');
            }
```

В 2.1 такого примера нет. Как тоже самое реализовать в новой версии api ?
примеров нет. а понять как делать могу только на примерах :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во второй версии почти ничего и не поменялось в этом плане.
Также вам нужно отслеживать изменение границ карты [boundschange](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map.html#event_detail__event-boundschange) (что будет и при масштабировании и при движении) и отправлять в URL полученные данные, например центра и масштаба.

```
var centerURL, zoomURL
// Отслеживаем смещение карты
myMap.events.add('boundschange', function (e) {
    //получаем координаты и масштаб
    centerURL=e.get('newCenter')
    zoomURL=e.get('newZoom')
    //кидаем полученный хэш в URL
    document.location.hash = "&ll="+centerURL.toString()+"&z="+zoomURL.toString()
})
```

Пример на фидле дополнен выводом URL, поскольку карта там работает во фрейме:
https://jsfiddle.net/gdvo7qL3/

Comment: не то. я хочу на своей карте свой url (на мой сайт) на каждое движение в карте. Как это было реализовано в версии 1.1

Comment: пример www.hibiny.com/map/polyarnye_zori/#&ll=32.48925,67.371621&spn=0.077505,0.016528

Comment: Изменил ответ под вашу задачу.